# CSS - placing div below fixed positioned div

Tags: html, css

On my page I have fixed position for a `main-section` and a `top-bar`. Main section takes up the 100vh. I need to somehow put the `#drawer` div below the `main-section` but not sure how to do that?

This is the structure of the html:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#main-section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 77px;
}
#drawer {
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: $charcoal;
  //display: none;

}
.top-barz {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="main-section">
    <div id="top-bar">
    </div>
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="carousel">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="drawer">
    <div id="item-detail">
    </div>
    <div id="item-detail-carousel">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The solution was to place it below it like this:

```
#drawer { z-index: 5; position: absolute; top: 100vh; }
```

Comment: put #drawer div after main-content

Comment: below main-section but still in screen size? or to get to it by scrolling?

Comment: no, I wanted to hide it, but I found a solution, I will update my question with the solution

Answer (score 0):

Simply use z-index to do that - [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

#### Example

```css
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    #main-section {
      z-index: 3;
      background-color: green;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top:77px;
    }

    #drawer {
      z-index: 2;
      position: fixed;
      max-height: 100%;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: gray;
      //display: none;
    }

    .top-barz {
       position: fixed;
       top: 0;
     }
```

```html
<div id="app">

    <div id="main-section">

       <div id="top-bar">
       </div>

       <div id="header">
       </div>

       <div id="carousel">
       </div>

    </div>

    <div id="drawer">

      <div id="item-detail">
      </div>

      <div id="item-detail-carousel">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the tags as fixed means, you just add the following **css code**

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add new div as a wrapper or else use `#app` div itself and apply fixed positioning to it with `overflow: auto`. Later you can add any number of DOM inside it with default position or `position: relative` of any height so that they'll flow one after the other.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
#app {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  height: calc(100% - 77px);
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 77px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#main-section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
}
#drawer {
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="main-section">
      <div id="top-bar">
      </div>
      <div id="header">
      </div>
      <div id="carousel">
      </div>
    </div>


    <div id="drawer">
      <div id="item-detail">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam lorem leo, aliquam id eros eu, auctor imperdiet ipsum. Morbi maximus justo nunc, sit amet sodales massa molestie ac. Maecenas arcu magna, vestibulum nec nunc id, faucibus viverra est.
        In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam molestie ante tellus. Nulla sodales sodales sollicitudin. Nam ac vestibulum ipsum. Phasellus blandit commodo lacus semper efficitur.</div>
      <div id="item-detail-carousel">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```